# Use adjtime() as non priviledged user

Tags: centos, privileges, ntp, setuid, unix-timestamp

I am running CentOS 5.4 and was wondering if there is any way of using the "adjtime()" system call as a non-root user.

Thanks in advance, really appreciate it